# Do newer versions of BJam support backwards compatibility with older versions of Boost?

Tags: boost, bjam

I'm trying to build version 1.35 of Boost with the newest version of bjam that is bundled with version 1.42 Boost. Will this adversely affect the results of the build? Is this even possible?

The reason I'm trying to do this is because the newest version of BJam has support for command line options that are not included in the older version of BJam that comes bundled with 1.35 of boost.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is supposed to work. You might want to double-check, with the --debug-configuration option, that the new Boost.Build version is indeed used, as opposed to the version bundled with 1.35.